# Generate chunks of code (functions, variables) from array (forEach)?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, eval

I have this chunk of code:

```
foo.bar('run', function () {       
  var text1 = foo.url('./src/url/text1.txt')
          .go(bar.do({ something }))
          .also(bar({
              variable: 1,
              else: 2,
          }).on('exception', doSomething ))
          .also(bar.url('.src/url/source'))

  var textLong = foo.url('./src/url/textLong.txt')
          .go(bar.do({ something }))
          .also(bar({
              variable: 1,
              else: 2,
          }).on('exception', doSomething ))
          .also(bar.url('.src/url/source'))

  var text = foo.url('./src/url/text.txt')
          .go(bar.do({ something }))
          .also(bar({
              variable: 1,
              else: 2,
          }).on('exception', doSomething ))
          .also(bar.url('.src/url/source'))

  return myCustomFunction(text1, textLong, text);
}
```

As you can see it's as anti-DRY as possible, every variable is the same excepting variable name and file name (foo.url).

I've been wondering if it is possible to make it simpler, something of the lines of:

```
var files = [ 'text1', 'textLong', 'text'];
```

And then:

```
foo.bar('run', function () {    
  files.forEach(function(fileName){
        var fileName = foo.url('./src/url/'+ fileName + '.txt')
        .go(bar.do({ something }))
        .also(bar({
            variable: 1,
            else: 2,
        }).on('exception', doSomething ))
        .also(bar.url('.src/url/source'))
  })

  return myCustomFunction(text1, textLong, text);
})
```

But the best I could get with my second approach is `text1 is not defined`. There are some questions on SO regarding dynamically creating variables, but they usually have the same names + I've never seen them combined with custom functions.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated this answer with tips from Ates Gora,  Thomas, Bergi.

Using some functions implemented in ES2016 the solution could look as follows:

```
foo.bar('run', function () {

  return myCustomFunction(

    ...[ 'text1', 'textLong', 'text' ].map(fileName => {

      return foo.url(`./src/url/${fileName}.txt`)
        .go(bar.do({ something }))
        .also(bar({
          variable: 1,
          else: 2,
        })
        .on('exception', doSomething ))
        .also(bar.url('.src/url/source'));

     });

  );

});
```

Comment: Or even: `\`./src/url/${fileName}.txt\``

Comment: Also, use `const` instead of `let` for the constant array of strings above.

Comment: it should be `return myCustomFunction( ...resultOfFilesMap );` not `...files`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) do collect the results of performing an operation over the items in an array and then [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call a function using an array of would-be arguments:

```
foo.bar('run', function () {    
  var results = files.map(function(fileName){
    return foo.url('./src/url/'+ fileName + '.txt')
      .go(bar.do({ something }))
      .also(bar({
        variable: 1,
        else: 2,
      })
      .on('exception', doSomething ))
      .also(bar.url('.src/url/source'));
  });

  return myCustomFunction.apply(null, results);
});
```

Comment: Will your solution alter order of my files somehow? Because it seems to be working but textLong.txt has some dependencies in text1.txt and now I'm getting "undefined variable" errors :( (I've been using foo/bar/txt as an dummy example, in fact I'm using Gulp with coffeeScript files here). Thank you!

Comment: No, `.map()` preserves the order.

Comment: I'm merging streams (myCustomFunction is "merge" IRL): https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge

Answer (score 1):

Never use dynamic variables. You want to use an array instead:

```
foo.bar('run', function () {    
    var files = [ 'text1', 'textLong', 'text'];
    var texts = files.map(function(fileName) {
//                    ^^^ get back the results
        return foo.url('./src/url/'+ fileName + '.txt')
//      ^^^^^^ don't assign to anything
        .go(bar.do({ something }))
        .also(bar({
            variable: 1,
            else: 2,
        }).on('exception', doSomething ))
        .also(bar.url('.src/url/source'))
  })

  return myCustomFunction(texts[0], texts[1], texts[2]);
})
```

Comment: It seems to be working just fine, but somehow it breaks order of loading these files, please see coment under @Ates Goral answer. Thanks for great answer though!

Comment: What do you mean by "has some dependencies"? There is nothing in the code about such a thing. My answer does exactly the same as your original code; of course both might involve some race conditions.